# Flex Advanced data grid wordwrapping

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I have an AdvancedDataGrid component, which has AdvancedDataGridColumn's that are rendered using MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer. When user stretches any columns, I want all rows to adjust it's height. So, I set variableRowHeight to true and wordWrap to true.

The problem is that it doesn't always readjust its height. Stretching a column will cause it to overflows into another row. Now, if i just click on the column separator, it will readjust. So basically, first stretching it and then just clicking on column separator solves the overflow problem.

Anyone encounter this overflow issue before?

**Update**

Step1 (Initial):

[image: Initial Screenshot]

Step2 (After first re-size):

[image: After first re-size]

Step3 (After clicking on column separator):

[image: After clicking on column separator]

**ItemRenderer:**

```
<fx:Component className="nameRenderer">
        <s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer width="100%">
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout />
            </s:layout>
            <mx:Image source="application/documentManager/mimeTypeIcons/{data.img}" toolTip="{data.tooltip}"
                      horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" />
            <mx:Text top="5" left="5" right="5" bottom="5" text="{data.data.name}" toolTip="{data.tooltip}" width="100%" />
        </s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my last project, i did a lot with the adg.
But i never had this issue. Can you give me a Screenshot?

I had some probems with the scrollbars. After installing FlashBuilder Burrito with the hero-SDK, this issue gone away.
They did a few things with adg and the dg is now also available as a spark.

Probably this will solve your issue?
BR
Frank

Comment: Hi, i would try this in burrito. This will be a seperate installation. If this is no option for you, can you please post your ItemRenderer. So I can try this in my both envoirments.